# Convert character value to command R

Tags: r, assign

Imagine I have character vector for which I want to assign values.

```
charac <- c("i", "j", "k") # character vector;
numb <- 1:3                # values, which I want to assign to 'charac' vector;
```

This part is easy with several lines of code:

```
for (m in 1:length(charac)){
   assign(charac[m], numb[m])}
```

But imagine I have character vector length of 100 and values in numb are extracted from text files in my computer. My life would be hundred times easier if would be way to reach values not in way like this

```
> c(i, j)
[1] 1 2
```

but in something like this:

```
> charac[1:2]
[1] "i" "j"
```

Now answer is "i", "j", but I would like to see '1 2'.

Thank you for your all views, answers and advices!

Comment: Why would you want 100 variables in the global environment?  I would recommend a list instead.  `setNames(as.list(numb), charac)`.  Or if they are always single values, an atomic vector ... `setNames(numb, charac)`.  Access is easy with `[` and/or `[[`

Comment: I have to reach numb values through 'charac' vector. In my real data I can't reach 'numb' that easily as in this example.

Comment: Try `x <- setNames(as.list(numb), charac)` then access `i` with `x[["i"]]` or `x[[charac[1]]]` or `x$i`

Comment: Thank you for saving my day! I got it, everything works like a charm.;]